# Why is Visual Studios not building new code?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

The new code that I am writing is not being added to the actual project, so the project window runs the same project over and over no matter how i change it. I've saved the project many times, restarted visual studios, but the problem remains. Im pretty new to this so this is probably not a bug, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you use the build command?

Comment: What's that? Can you find it on the IDE or is it an actual code snippet?

Comment: Look at the Build menu!